# Foreign key problems in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I get an error "unknown column "CustID" in foreign key definition"
and "no such table: serviceticket"

Can anyone help me?

```
drop table if exists customer;
drop table if exists serviceticket; 

PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; 

create table customer (CustID char(6) not null primary key UNIQUE, 
    CustNAME TEXT, 
    STREET TEXT, 
    CITY TEXT, 
    ZIP INT(5),
    EMAIL VARCHAR, 
    PHONENUMBER INT(10)
    );

create table serviceticket (TicketID char(4) not null primary key, 
    TicketNO char(5), 
    WatchID char(6), 
    DateRecieved char(6), 
    ExpectedDelivery char(6), 
    COMMENTS text, 
    DateReturned char(6),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES customer (CustID)
    );

insert into customer (CustID, CustNAME, STREET, CITY, ZIP, PHONENUMBER, EMAIL) 
    values (170362, 'James', 'Vvegen', New York, 12345, 8170710520, 'brt92@outlook.com');

insert into serviceticket (TicketID, WatchID, CustID, DateRecieved, DateReturned, ExpectedDelivery, COMMENTS, DateReturned)
    values (6745, 87463, 098636, 124319, 362836, 683743, 'Nothing to say', 583728);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will work.

This has three changes instead of using `FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES customer (CustID)`, which requires the column **CustID** in the **serviceticket** table to have been defined; `CustID REFERENCES customer (CustID)`, this defines the CustID column and sets the Foreign Key constraint.

The second change replaces **098636** which will result in a Foreign Key constraint conflict, with **170362** which is a value that exists in the **CustID** column of the **Customer** table.

e.g. :-

This works (after the table has been correctly defined) :-

```
    insert into serviceticket (TicketID, WatchID, CustID, DateRecieved, DateReturned, ExpectedDelivery, COMMENTS, DateReturned)
    values (6745, 87463, '170362', 124319, 362836, 683743, 'Nothing to say', 583728)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.082s
```

This will (as per the message) fail

```
insert into serviceticket (TicketID, WatchID, CustID, DateRecieved, DateReturned, ExpectedDelivery, COMMENTS, DateReturned)
values (6745, 87463, 098636, 124319, 362836, 683743, 'Nothing to say', 583728)
> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
> Time: 0s
```

The third change is swapping the order in which the tables are dropped.

## The working code

```
drop table if exists serviceticket; -- <<<<<<<<<< if not coding ON DELETE CASCADE the children have to be deleted first (so moved before dropping customer table) 
drop table if exists customer;


PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; 

create table customer (CustID char(6) not null primary key UNIQUE, 
    CustNAME TEXT, 
    STREET TEXT, 
    CITY TEXT, 
    ZIP INT(5),
    EMAIL VARCHAR, 
    PHONENUMBER INT(10)
    );

create table serviceticket (TicketID char(4) not null primary key, 
    TicketNO char(5), 
    WatchID char(6), 
    DateRecieved char(6), 
    ExpectedDelivery char(6), 
    COMMENTS text, 
    DateReturned char(6),
    CustID REFERENCES customer (CustID) -- <<<<<<<<<< defines the column and foreign key
    );

insert into customer (CustID, CustNAME, STREET, CITY, ZIP, PHONENUMBER, EMAIL) 
    values (170362, 'James', 'Vvegen', 'New York', 12345, 8170710520, 'brt92@outlook.com');

insert into serviceticket (TicketID, WatchID, CustID, DateRecieved, DateReturned, ExpectedDelivery, COMMENTS, DateReturned)
    values (6745, 87463, 
        '170362', -- <<<<<<<<<< MUST match a value in CustID column of the customer table (changed to work)
        124319, 362836, 683743, 'Nothing to say', 583728);
```

## Additional

you may wish to consider using (or variants thereof):-

```
CustID REFERENCES customer (CustID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

[4.3. ON DELETE and ON UPDATE Actions](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions)

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand:)

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `CustID` prior of the definition of the foreign key:

```
create table serviceticket (TicketID char(4) not null primary key, 
    TicketNO char(5), 
    WatchID char(6), 
    DateRecieved char(6), 
    ExpectedDelivery char(6), 
    COMMENTS text, 
    DateReturned char(6),
    CustID char(6),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES customer(CustID)
    );
```